For all natural numbers $1\leq n, 0<a^n<b^n$ using mathematical induction
Knowing that $0<a<b$
I have been stuck on this for quite a while, I'm doing this
When $n = k$, we can assume that:
$$
0 < a^k < b^k \space \forall \space k\geq1
$$
Our inductive step would be for $n = k + 1$:
$$
0 < a^{k+1}<b^{k+1}
$$
$$
0 < a.a^k < b. b^k
$$
i know we are supposed to use the fact that $1\leq k$ and $0<a^k<b^k$ but i cannot figure out how to continue

You forgot the basic case, which cannot be assumed. Take, say, $a=10^6$ and $b=1$. However, once we know that $a<b$, what do you conclude?

Please, choose the appropriate tags.

This is false. Take, for example $a=b=1$

@jjagmath i forgot to add that it is given that 0 < a < b, my apologies! and about the tags since i am new i can only use the most popular tags

$a<b$, so $a \cdot a^k < b \cdot a^k$.  Then $a^k < b^k$, so $b \cdot a^k < b \cdot b^k$.

@EricTowers I got there after continuing to solve it for awhile, but how can we conclude that
$$
a^{k+1} < b^{k+1}
$$
i know the RHS becomes b^(k+1) but how does the LHS become a^(k+1)

We are given $0 < a < b$.
First consider $k = 1$.  We wish to show
$$  0 < a^1 < b^1  \text{.}  $$
Recall that $a^1 = a$ and $b^1 = b$, so this reduces to
$$  0 < a < b  \text{,}  $$
which is given.
Now suppose for the natural number $k \geq 1$ we have shown $0 < a^k < b^k$.  We wish to show $0 < a^{k+1} < b^{k+1}$.  Since $0 < a$ and $0 < a^k$, $0 < a \cdot a^k = a^{k+1}$.  We have
\begin{align*}
0 < a^{k+1} &= a \cdot a^k  \\
    &< b \cdot a^k  &&\text{because $a < b$ and $0 < a^k$}  \\
    &< b \cdot b^k  &&\text{because $a^k < b^k$ and $0 < b$}  \\
    &= b^{k+1}  \text{.}
\end{align*}
We have obtained $0 < a^{k+1} < b^{k+1}$.
Therefore, for $0 < a < b$, $a^{k} < b^{k}$ for each natural number $k$.

okay this makes it really clear! thank you so much, so sorry for the bother
